# Concatenating two torch tensors of different shapes in pytorch

Tags: pytorch, concatenation, tensor, torch

I have two torch tensors. One with shape `[64, 4, 300]`, and one with shape `[64, 300]`. How can I concatenate these two tensors to obtain the resultant tensor of shape `[64, 5, 300]`. I'm aware about the `tensor.cat` function used for this, but in order to use that function, I need to reshape the second tensor in order to match the number of dimensions of the tensor. I've heard that reshaping of the tensors should not be done, as it might mess up the data in the tensor. How can I do this concatenation?

I've tried reshaping, but following part makes me more doubtful about such reshaping.

```
a = torch.rand(64,300)

a1 = a.reshape(64,1,300)

list(a1[0]) == list(a)
Out[32]: False
```

Answer (score 8):

You have to use `torch.cat` along first dimension and do `unsqueeze` at the first one as well, like this:

```
import torch

first = torch.randn(64, 4, 300)
second = torch.randn(64, 300)

torch.cat((first, second.unsqueeze(dim=1)), dim=1)
# Shape: [64, 5, 300]
```

It won't mess up with your data, it's only adding superficial `1` dimension (`reshape` doesn't if done correctl anyway).

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I shouldn't use reshape here right? Also, what does `unsqueeze` do? Why is it safe to use?

Comment: you could use `reshape(64, 1, 300)` as well, but it's verbose. `unsqueeze` adds `1` dimension between `64` and `300` so shapes are broadcastable. It is safe as it only changes internal data representation (it is kept in continguous C++ array) with things like strides etc. Data is copied only if it cannot be "reshaped" in this non-invasive way (if you don't want copy to happen ever you should use `view`). But you have to know how it works so you won't mix up dimensions accidentally.